# Conditional filtering in groups using data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have two datasets, which I want to first join and then filter based on conditions, for each group `(id, code)`. For each group, if the `end_date` is earlier than `date`, I want to simply filter for the latest `end_date`. Otherwise, I want to filter for the rows where `date` is between two columns, `start_date` and `end_date`.

I have coded this using `dplyr` and it works - see below.

```
left_join(df, df_match, by='id') %>% 
group_by(id, code) %>%
mutate(is.max = max(end_date) < date) %>%
filter(case_when(
  is.max == T ~ end_date == max(end_date),
  is.max == F ~ date >= start_date & date <= end_date
))
```

However, this code is very slow for my 1+ million row datasets. I am curious if it's possible to achieve the same thing using `data.table`, which is usually much faster?

Comment: Interesting question but, please, provide a [mcve] including the expected result. As the question currently is written, it is unclear which column is originating from which data.frame. To find clever answers it is necessary to get the full picture and also to have some data for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't test this without data but `data.table` translation of `dplyr` code would be -

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
setDT(df_match)

res <- merge(df, df_match, by = 'id')

res[, .SD[if(max(end_date) < date) end_date == max(end_date) else 
  date >= start_date & date <= end_date],  .(id, code)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting an error, though, that `In if (max(end_date) < date) end_date == max(end_date) else date >=  ... : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`.

Comment: Try wrapping the condition in `any`  i.e `if(any(max(end_date) < date, na.rm = TRUE))`